# Script file doesn't load for code inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bMte.png)I have an template i make that into single page application using ng-view and ng-route in angular but that template already have some theme script file it does not
load for other pages...It only effecting main page other page not....like responsive datatable bootstrap icon...please help

Comment: Please provide some code, so we know exactly what your issue is.

Comment: Provide your code. I think you have using `ng-view` in wrong place

Comment: didnt load theme script file of template if it makes as single page application using ng-view